PL/SQL Continue Statement
Why would the below code still produce 2 at the end? (after 1 and oracle)
'Continue' means to stop when i>1, right?
Thanks.
BEGIN
for i in 1..2
  loop
  dbms_output.put_line (i);
  continue when i>1;
  dbms_output.put_line ('oracle');
  end loop;
END;


Continue doesn't mean to stop when i>1. You can use 'EXIT' statement to break to loop.
More info about 'CONTINUE' can be found here.
You can check the following snippet to see when the loop is broken:
BEGIN
for i in 1..2
  loop
  exit when i>1;
  dbms_output.put_line (i);
  dbms_output.put_line ('oracle');
  end loop;
END;

